# Azure easy auth API

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I've setup my mvc web app to use Azure easy auth. I need to pass the user role to the application code.

I've seen that easy auth already publishes an API, so that I can call /.auth/me and retrieve the user login. I can't find any documentation on this API - does it support other requests that can be used to pass a role?

Alternative would be to use the token store to call the graph API, but as I only need basic info, I wondered if there was a simpler way?

Thanks,

Mark

Comment: To further clarify this question.... I have my web app setup to use azure ad b2c and I have my roles defined in groups. Specifically I'm trying to understand if I can find a signed in users group from the easy auth api without having to call in to the graph api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to know which application role has been assigned for current login user :
[image]

you could check the `roles` claim in ID token :[image]

Update :

Currently , you can't get group claims in azure ad B2C with easy auth , you could find same user voice [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10123836-get-user-membership-groups-in-the-claims-with-ad-b) .

Comment: I think this may be something different - I don't recognise your screenshot. I have an MVC web app on Azure which is using easy authentication / authorisation against a B2C active directory.

Comment: what do you mean by 'user role' ? Do you have a system which enables external user login (azure ad b2c) , and you want to manager the role of user in you system ?

Comment: Yes, exactly correct. In fact I'm passing the role to the Power BI API in order to invoke RLS if that helps to clarify. Hence, user logs in via AAD B2C. They are assigned a particular role. The role is passed to the Power BI API in the code which returns the data they are allowed to see in the embedded report.

Comment: To answer you new commnet , currently , you can't get group claims in azure ad B2C with easy auth ,  you could find same user voice [here](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/10123836-get-user-membership-groups-in-the-claims-with-ad-b)

Comment: Thanks Nan Yu. I've voted for the enhancement as I think it's a useful feature.